# SQL group by not working as wanted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a headache with this, i have 2 tables I'm working with in this Query, for contextual purposes let me describe what I'm trying to do with this.

I am building a dashboard that will display the amount of time that certain order has been per every process it has to go thru, in this case i am having 4 processes, and while it hasn't been thru a process it will need to display the amount until that time(this is a query that is queried every sec via web browser.

So my problem is that in the first process where the time is calculated if there is no activity registered per order it will display since the registered Date(FechaRegistro) but for some reason if i have more than 1 order in the first process only the 1st one will display correctly, the rest will display a NULL value, and the rest of the processes do work correctly, its just the first I'm having problems with.

Ordenes Table

```
Id  Numero  flujo_id    LastOrder   FechaRegistro
18  2         1             0   2015-09-26 19:13:27
19  3         1             0   2015-09-26 19:14:04
20  4         1             0   2015-09-26 19:14:14
```

Actividad table:

```
Id    TiempoInicio        Proceso_Id   Orden_Id
1   2015-09-26 20:07:26     1           20
```

QUERY

```sql
SELECT 
    Ordenes.Id, Numero, FechaRegistro, m.P1, a.P2, b.P3, c.P4
FROM
    Ordenes
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Ordenes.id,
        IF(MIN(Actividad.TiempoInicio) IS NULL,SEC_TO_TIME(timestampdiff(SECOND,Ordenes.FechaRegistro,now())) ,SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Ordenes.FechaRegistro, MIN(Actividad.TiempoInicio)))) as P1
    FROM
    Ordenes
    LEFT JOIN Actividad ON Ordenes.id = Actividad.Orden_id
    GROUP BY Actividad.Orden_id) AS m ON Ordenes.id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P2
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('1' , '2')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS a ON Ordenes.id = a.Orden_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P3
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('2' , '3')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS b ON Ordenes.id = b.Orden_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P4
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('3' , '4')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS c ON Ordenes.id = c.Orden_id
ORDER BY id
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID Numero  FechaRegistro         P1           P2         P3        P4

18  2   2015-09-26 19:13:27     00:54:38    NULL        NULL      NULL
19  3   2015-09-26 19:14:04     NULL        NULL        NULL      NULL      
20  4   2015-09-26 19:14:14     00:53:12    00:00:39    NULL      NULL
```

The desired Result should display the value the same value on P1 in Id 19 as 18, since none of them have an activity on the table recorded.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cc1dc/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i couldn't actually solve the issue but i did manage to get my wanted result, changing a bit my logic, i got the registeredDate in the activity table with a process id of 0 and made the next SQL

```
SELECT 
    Ordenes.Id, Numero, FechaRegistro, m.P1, a.P2, b.P3, c.P4,(FechaRegistro) as Cierre
FROM
    Ordenes
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P1
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('0' , '1')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS m ON Ordenes.id = m.Orden_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P2
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('1' , '2')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS a ON Ordenes.id = a.Orden_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P3
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('2' , '3')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS b ON Ordenes.id = b.Orden_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    Orden_Id,
        IF(MIN(TiempoInicio)=MAX(TiempoInicio),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), now())),SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(TiempoInicio), MAX(TiempoInicio)))) as P4
    FROM
    Actividad
    WHERE
    Proceso_Id IN ('3' , '4')
    GROUP BY Orden_id) AS c ON Ordenes.id = c.Orden_id
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use GROUP BY out of your subquerys

Comment: How so?, if then how will i be able to group my processes?